# Yii with PHP Storm Auto Complete and Class Recognition

Tags: php, yii, phpstorm

I've just started using the Yii Framework (A fantastic one at that!) and am using PHP Storm 5 with it.

I have separated the testdrive file from the Yii framework and just changed the paths in the index.php file which all works but how do I now get code completion and the IDE to recognise all the yii system classes?

I have googled and read heaps of stuff but it's all so confusing and not explained very well. Can anyone out there give me a few steps to follow?

Comment: Post your answer as an answer below so anyone else having the same issue can find it more easily :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I figured it out, pretty easy. All you have to do is go File → Settings → Project settings → PHP → PHP Home → Add. and add the path to your framework folder in yii whereever it is.